# sql query is long so it take long time to fetch

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sqla = <<<EOT
  SELECT
      jm.name,
      sum(m_01) as jantot,
      sum(m_02) as febtot,
      sum(m_03) as martot,
      sum(m_04) as aprtot,
      sum(m_05) as maytot,
      sum(m_06) as juntot,
      sum(m_07) as jultot,
      sum(m_08) as augtot,
      sum(m_09) as septot,
      sum(m_10) as octtot,
      sum(m_11) as novtot,
      sum(m_12) as dectot,
      (IFNULL(SUM(m_01), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(m_02), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(m_03), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(m_04), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(m_05), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(m_06), 0) +  IFNULL(SUM(m_07), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(m_08), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(m_09), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(m_10), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(m_11), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(m_12), 0)) as gtot
  FROM
      jr1_$year s,
      resourcelist m ,
      `journalmaster` jm
  WHERE
      jm.journalid = s.journalid
      AND jm.Platform = m.platform
      AND m.univ_id=s.univ_id
      AND m.Year = :year
      AND m.report = 'jr1'
      AND m.memID = :memID
      AND m.resource = :resource
  GROUP BY
      jm.name
  ORDER BY
      gtot DESC
EOT;


$sql_statement1 = $infistat->prepare($sqla);
$sql_statement1->bindParam(':year', $year, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql_statement1->bindParam(':memID', $memID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql_statement1->bindParam(':resource', $resource, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql_statement1->execute();
$result_table = $sql_statement1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

any suggestions??

Comment: Probably a pure SQL issue. I.e. you can remove the php/ajax/pdo part of the question to make it clearer!

Comment: I suggest you to provide a lot more information regarding the issue you are facing because based on the above your question cannot be answered. 1) What does your query try to achieve? How many records are there in the affected tables? How long does it take your query to fetch the data? What indexes are defined on the affected tables? What's the output of the explain?

Comment: If heavily depends upon the design of your SQL tables and the amount of data that you have in these. Without a in-depth knowledge of these things, people will not be able to help. I suggest that you ask other people involved in your project/company instead of asking here.